# get names of quoted list without evaluation

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I've got a quoted list

```
quote(list(orders = .N,
           total_quantity = sum(quantity)))
```

(that I eventually `eval` in the `j` part of a `data.table`)

What I would like is to extract the `names` of that list without having to evaluate the expression because outside of the correct environment evaluating the expression will produce an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list doesn't have any names at that point. It's not even a list. It's a call to the `list()` function. But that said you can parse that function call and extract name parameter. For example

```
x <- quote(list(orders = .N,
    total_quantity = sum(quantity)))
names(as.list(x))[-1]
# [1] "orders"         "total_quantity"
```

That `as.list()` on the expression turns the function call into a (named) list without evaluation.

Comment: What about just `names(x)[-1]`? Which is weird to me, since `attributes(x)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: Good point @RichScriven. There must be some coercion going on somewhere but I can't find it. The lack of a names attribute is interesting.